# Print Trace Debugger

Tags: beginner, scala, error-handling, meta-programming

Notice: The original library has since been replaced by:

https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/scala-trace-debug

---

See my [Scala print trace debugger](https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/debugtrace). This project is used for lightweight debugging sort of like the [Haskell Debug.Trace module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html). The README, the documentation, and the test cases need work.

To test it out, see the code below or do:

```
git clone https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/debugtrace
```

And open it up in IntelliJ as an SBT Project. To run:

> IntelliJ > Run > Edit Configurations > Add New Configuration > Application (or "SBT Task")

Code to be reviewed:

```
package info.collaboration_station.debug

/**
  * Created by johnreed on 3/12/16.
  */
object Debug {

  /**
    * Stack offset is 2 because the first row in the stack trace is Thread and the second row is internal call.
    */
  protected[debug] val stackOffset = 2

  private var _traceOut_? = true

  /**
    * Tells you whether tracing to standard out is on or off.
    * Note that disabling the "traceStdOut" feature does not disable the "assertStdOut" feature.
    */
  def traceOutOn_? = _traceOut_?

  private var _traceErr_? = true

  /**
    * Tells you whether tracing to standard error is on or off.
    * Note that disabling the "trace" feature does not disable the "assert" feature.
    */
  def traceErrOn_? = _traceErr_?

  private var _fatalAssert_? = true

  /**
    * Tells you whether fatal asserts are on or off.
    */
  def fatalAssertOn_? = _fatalAssert_?

  private var _nonFatalAssert_? = true

  /**
    * Tells you whether non-fatal asserts are on or off.
    */
  def nonFatalAssertOn_? = _nonFatalAssert_?

  // these lines disable and enable particular features.

  def traceErrOn_!() = { _traceErr_? = true }

  def traceErrOff_!() = { _traceErr_? = false }

  def traceOutOn_!() = { _traceOut_? = true }

  def traceOutOff_!() = { _traceOut_? = false }

  def fatalAssertOn_!() = { _fatalAssert_? = true }

  def fatalAssertOff_!() = { _fatalAssert_? = false }

  def nonFatalAssertOn_!() = { _nonFatalAssert_? = true }

  def nonFatalAssertOff_!() = { _nonFatalAssert_? = false }

  /**
    * Enables tracing and asserts, including fatal assertions.
    */
  def enableEverything_!() = {
    traceErrOn_!()
    traceOutOn_!()
    fatalAssertOn_!()
    nonFatalAssertOn_!()
  }

  /**
    * Disables tracing and asserts. Both fatal and non-fatal assertions are disabled. Does not disable print or println.
    */
  def disableEverything_!() = {
    traceErrOff_!()
    traceOutOff_!()
    fatalAssertOff_!()
    nonFatalAssertOff_!()
  }

  /**
    * A fatal assertion. Debug.assert( 1 + 2 = 3 )
    * Terminates the program with exit code "7"
    *
    * @param assertion the assertion that must be true for the program to run. Can be a value or a function.
    * @param message the message to be printed to standard error on assertion failure
    */
  final def assert(assertion: => Boolean, message: String) = {
    if(!assertion && Debug.fatalAssertOn_?) {
      ImplicitTraceObject.traceInternalAssert(message, Int.MaxValue) // trace the max number of lines of stack trace to std error
    }
    System.exit(7)
  }

  /**
    * A fatal assertion. Debug.assert( 1 + 2 = 3 )
    * Terminates the program with exit code "7"
    *
    * @param assertion the assertion that must be true for the program to run. Can be a value or a function.
    * @param message the message to be printed to standard out on assertion failure
    */
  final def assertStdOut(assertion: => Boolean, message: String) = {
    if(!assertion && Debug.fatalAssertOn_?) {
      ImplicitTraceObject.traceInternalAssert(message, Int.MaxValue, useStdOut_? = true) // trace the max number of lines of stack trace to std out
    }
    System.exit(7)
  }

  /**
    * Like Debug.assert, but does not terminate the application.
    */
  final def assertNonFatal(assertion: => Boolean, message: String) = {
    if(!assertion && Debug.nonFatalAssertOn_?) {
      ImplicitTraceObject.traceInternalAssert(message, Int.MaxValue) // trace the max number of lines of stack trace to std error
    }
  }

  /**
    * Like Debug.assertStdOut, but does not terminate the application.
    */
  final def assertNonFatalStdOut(assertion: => Boolean, message: String) = {
    if(!assertion && Debug.nonFatalAssertOn_?) {
      ImplicitTraceObject.traceInternalAssert(message, Int.MaxValue, useStdOut_? = true) // trace the max number of lines of stack trace to std out
    }
  }
}
```

File where `ImplicitTraceObject` is located:

The below file (where `ImplicitTraceObject` is located) is what does the actual printing:

```
package info.collaboration_station.debug

/**
  * Wrapper class for a value that can be traced
  * @param me the original value inside the wrapper
  * @tparam MyType the original type of the value inside the wrapper
  */
final class ImplicitTrace[MyType](val me: MyType) {
  /**
    * Same as System.out.print(this), but with the function name after the object.
    */
  final def print() = {
    if(me != null) {
      System.out.print(me.toString)
    } else {
      System.out.print("null")
    }
  }
  /**
    * Same as System.out.println(this), but with the function name after the object.
    */
  final def println() = {
    if(me != null) {
      System.out.println(me.toString)
    } else {
      System.out.println("null")
    }
  }
  /**
    * Same as System.err.print(this), but with the function name after the object.
    */
  final def printStdErr() = {
    if(me != null) {
      System.err.print(me.toString)
    } else {
      System.err.print("null")
    }
  }
  /**
    * Same as System.err.println(this), but with the function name after the object.
    */
  final def printlnStdErr() = {
    if(me != null) {
      System.err.println(me.toString)
    } else {
      System.err.println("null")
    }
  }
  /**
    * Prints out this object with 1 lines of stack trace to standard error.
    * @return The thing that was just printed.
    */
  final def trace: MyType = ImplicitTraceObject.traceInternal(me, 1)
  /**
    * Prints out this object to standard error with a user specified number of lines of stack trace.
    * @param linesOfStackTrace The number of lines of stack trace.
    * @return The thing that was just printed.
    */
  final def trace(linesOfStackTrace: Int): MyType = ImplicitTraceObject.traceInternal(me, linesOfStackTrace)
  /**
    * Prints out this object with 1 lines of stack trace to standard out.
    * @return The thing that was just printed.
    */
  final def traceStdOut: MyType = ImplicitTraceObject.traceInternal(me, 1, useStdOut_? = true)
  /**
    * Prints out this object to standard out with a user specified number of lines of stack trace.
    * @param linesOfStackTrace The number of lines of stack trace.
    * @return The thing that was just printed.
    */
  final def traceStdOut(linesOfStackTrace: Int): MyType = ImplicitTraceObject.traceInternal(me, linesOfStackTrace, useStdOut_? = true)
  /**
    * A fatal assertion, but with the function name after the object. 1.assert( _ + 2 = 3 )
    * Terminates the program with exit code "7"
    * @param assertion the assertion that must be true for the program to run
    * @param message the message to be printed to standard error on assertion failure
    */
  final def assert(assertion: (MyType) => Boolean, message: String) = {
    if(! assertion(me) && Debug.fatalAssertOn_?) {
      ImplicitTraceObject.traceInternalAssert(me, Int.MaxValue) // trace the max number of lines of stack trace to std error
    }
    System.exit(7)
  }
  /**
    * A fatal assertion, but with the function name after the object. 1.assert( _ + 2 = 3 )
    * Terminates the program with exit code "7"
    * @param assertion the assertion that must be true for the program to run
    * @param message the message to be printed  to standard out on assertion failure
    */
  final def assertStdOut(assertion: (MyType) => Boolean, message: String) = {
    if(! assertion(me) && Debug.fatalAssertOn_?) {
      ImplicitTraceObject.traceInternalAssert(me, Int.MaxValue, useStdOut_? = true) // trace the max number of lines of stack trace to std out
    }
    System.exit(7)
  }
  final def assertEquals(other: MyType, message: String) = {
    val assertionTrue_? = this == other
    if(! assertionTrue_? && Debug.fatalAssertOn_?) {
      ImplicitTraceObject.traceInternalAssert(me, Int.MaxValue) // trace the max number of lines of stack trace to std error
    }
    System.exit(7)
  }
  final def assertEqualsStdOut(other: MyType, message: String) = {
    val assertionTrue_? = this == other
    if(! assertionTrue_? && Debug.fatalAssertOn_?) {
      ImplicitTraceObject.traceInternalAssert(me, Int.MaxValue, useStdOut_? = true) // trace the max number of lines of stack trace to std out
    }
    System.exit(7)
  }
  final def assertNonFatal(assertion: (MyType) => Boolean, message: String) = {
    val assertionTrue_? = assertion(me)
    if(! assertionTrue_? && Debug.nonFatalAssertOn_?) {
      ImplicitTraceObject.traceInternalAssert(me, Int.MaxValue) // trace the max number of lines of stack trace to std error
    }
  }
  final def assertNonFatalStdOut(assertion: (MyType) => Boolean, message: String) = {
    val assertionTrue_? = assertion(me)
    if(! assertionTrue_? && Debug.nonFatalAssertOn_?) {
      ImplicitTraceObject.traceInternalAssert(me, Int.MaxValue, useStdOut_? = true) // trace the max number of lines of stack trace to std out
    }
  }
  final def assertNonFatalEquals(other: MyType, message: String) = {
    val assertionTrue_? = this == other
    if(! assertionTrue_? && Debug.nonFatalAssertOn_?) {
      ImplicitTraceObject.traceInternalAssert(me, Int.MaxValue) // trace the max number of lines of stack trace to std error
    }
  }
  final def assertNonFatalEqualsStdOut(other: MyType, message: String) = {
    val assertionTrue_? = this == other
    if(! assertionTrue_? && Debug.nonFatalAssertOn_?) {
      ImplicitTraceObject.traceInternalAssert(me, Int.MaxValue, useStdOut_? = true) // trace the max number of lines of stack trace to std out
    }
  }
}

/**
  * Contains static methods for ImplicitTraceObject
  */
object ImplicitTraceObject {
  /**
    * The offset of the first line from the base of the stack trace.
    * The +1 is necessary because the method call traceInternal adds one to the offset of the stack trace.
    */
  val newStackOffset = Debug.stackOffset + 1
  /**
    * Prints out the object with N lines of stack trace. Do not use with assertions.
    * @param toPrintOutNullable the object to print out. May be "null".
    * @param numStackLinesIntended N, the number of lines of stack trace intended. Defaults to zero actual lines of stack trace for negative values.
    * @param useStdOut_? Whether to use standard out for trace (as opposed to std error). Uses standard error by default.
    * @return The thing that was put into the first parameter
    */
  protected[debug] final def traceInternal[A](toPrintOutNullable: A, numStackLinesIntended: Int, useStdOut_? : Boolean = false): A = {
    if( !Debug.traceErrOn_? && !useStdOut_?) {
      return toPrintOutNullable // if tracing to standard error is off and we trace to standard error, return
    }
    if( !Debug.traceOutOn_? && useStdOut_?) {
      return toPrintOutNullable // if tracing to standard out is off and we trace to out, return
    }
    val numStackLines = if(numStackLinesIntended > 0) {
      numStackLinesIntended // the number of lines must be positive or zero
    } else {
      0
    }
    val stack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace
    val toPrintOut: String = if(toPrintOutNullable == null) {"null"} else {toPrintOutNullable.toString}
    var toPrint = "\"" + toPrintOut + "\"" + " in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName + ":"
    for (row <- 0 to Math.min(numStackLines - 1, stack.length - 1 - newStackOffset)) {
      val lineNumber = newStackOffset + row
      val stackLine = stack(lineNumber)
      // The java stack traces use a tab character, not a space
      val tab = "\t"
      toPrint += "\n" + tab + "at " + stackLine
    }
    toPrint += "\n"
    if(useStdOut_?) {
      System.out.println(toPrint)
    } else {
      System.err.println(toPrint)
    }
    toPrintOutNullable // return the origional thing, even if it is null.
  }
  /**
    * Prints out the object with N lines of stack trace. Meant to be used only for asserts.
    * @param toPrintOutNullable the object to print out. May be "null".
    * @param numStackLinesIntended N, the number of lines of stack trace intended. Defaults to zero actual lines of stack trace for negative values.
    * @param useStdOut_? Whether to use standard out for trace (as opposed to std error). Uses standard error by default.
    * @return The thing that was put into the first parameter
    */
  protected[debug] final def traceInternalAssert[A](toPrintOutNullable: A, numStackLinesIntended: Int, useStdOut_? : Boolean = false): A = {
    // Disabling trace does not also disable assert. They are two separate things.
    //if( !Debug.traceErrOn_? && !useStdOut_?) {
    //  return toPrintOutNullable // if tracing to standard error is off and we trace to standard error, return
    //}
    //if( !Debug.traceOutOn_? && useStdOut_?) {
    //  return toPrintOutNullable // if tracing to standard out is off and we trace to out, return
    //}
    val numStackLines = if(numStackLinesIntended > 0) {
      numStackLinesIntended // the number of lines must be positive or zero
    } else {
      0
    }
    val stack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace
    val toPrintOut: String = if(toPrintOutNullable == null) {"null"} else {toPrintOutNullable.toString}
    var toPrint = "\"" + toPrintOut + "\"" + " in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName + ":"
    for (row <- 0 to Math.min(numStackLines - 1, stack.length - 1 - newStackOffset)) {
      val lineNumber = newStackOffset + row
      val stackLine = stack(lineNumber)
      // The java stack traces use a tab character, not a space
      val tab = "\t"
      toPrint += "\n" + tab + "at " + stackLine
    }
    toPrint += "\n"
    if(useStdOut_?) {
      System.out.println(toPrint)
    } else {
      System.err.println(toPrint)
    }
    toPrintOutNullable // return the origional thing, even if it is null.
  }
}
```

This last file performs the implicit conversion to add functionality to objects in your code:

```
package info.collaboration_station
import info.collaboration_station.debug.ImplicitTrace

/**
  * Created by johnreed on 3/12/16.
  */
package object debug {
  import scala.language.implicitConversions // Warning: implicit conversions language feature

  /**
    * Converter method that puts the value "me" inside ImplicitTrace for additional functionality
    *
    * @param me the value to be put inside the wrapper
    * @tparam MyType the type of the value to be put inside the wrapper
    * @return A new ImplicitTrace wrapper which appends print trace related functionality to the value.
    */
  implicit def toTraceable[MyType](me: MyType) = new ImplicitTrace[MyType](me)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some formal remarks that do not concern the design choices made in the code.

#### Unnecessary Code

All the repeated functions like

```
final def println() = {
  if(me != null) {
    System.out.println(me.toString)
  } else {
    System.out.println("null")
  }
}
```

Can be shortened to

```
final def println() = println(me)
```

`toString()` (or `String.valueOf`) is invoked behind the scenes on the args passed to `System.out.print`. If the arg is `null`, "null" will also be output.

Please note that in Scala, `System.out.print*` is implicitly imported by the compiler and `print*` methods may be used directly.

#### Naming

There are some oddities in `Debug` fields and function names: underscores in names, suffixes like `_?` or `_!`. I suppose they have useful meanings, but this sort of naming is against [Scala naming conventions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html):

> Underscores in names (_) are not actually forbidden by the compiler, but are strongly discouraged as they have special meaning within the Scala syntax.

#### `System.exit` !?

Be very careful with `System.exit()` calls. Are you sure they are necessary in this code? Wouldn't there be a risk to break the applications of the users of this code? `System.exit()`, if not in `main` method, is generally a bad practice.

Comment: I agree on the null check.